# vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user id not integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь создать чат бота с системой игроков и локаций в VK. Для этого создана база данных в SQL и модуль с командами под неё же. Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке получить набор id пользователей на локации, для рассылки сообщений им, таблица возвращает список с типом string, хотя в таблице для этого столбца указан тип Integer и кроме целых чисел в нём ничего нет.

### Код основного бота:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
    user_id = event.user_id
    if event.text and status_message(user_id):
        player_name, players_on_location = db.get_players(user_id)
        send_message_player(f'Игрок {player_name} \n {event.text}', players = players_on_location)
```

Код для получения имени и Id пользователей на той же локации

```
 def get_players(self, special_id):
    same_location = self.cursor.execute('SELECT `current_location` FROM `user` WHERE `special_id` = ?',
                                        (special_id,)).fetchone()[0]
    name = self.cursor.execute('SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE `special_id` = ?', (special_id,)).fetchone()[0]
    players = self.cursor.execute('SELECT `uniq_id` FROM `user` WHERE `current_location` = ?', (same_location,)).fetchall()
    return name, players
```

Пытался преобразовать через Int обратно в integer, но поменялась только ошибка и вместо list появился tulpe
Ошибку: `vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id not integer` выдаёт при получении любого текста ботом.

Comment: Ну так `players_on_location` - это скорее всего список кортежей вида `[(номер_строки_выборки, id_игрока), ...]` Как вы вытаетесь с ним дальше работать, где этот код в вопросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку смог починить преобразованием кортежа сначала в list, а потом в int через map

```
 if event.text and status_message(user_id):
        try:
            player_name, players_on_location = db.get_players(user_id)
            for players in players_on_location:
                users = list(map(int, players))
                send_message_player(users, f'Игрок {player_name} \n {event.text}')
        except vk_api.exceptions.ApiError:
            pass
```

Тут ещё и частично моя ошибка, так как в `uniq_id` использованом в команде для ДБ, хранятся неповторяющиеся id, а не id чата с пользователем